# how to save file in desired path with StreamWriter

Tags: vb.net

I am saving a .csv file in my directory by giving the path with StreamWriter. Now i want to give the option to user to save that file desired path. how can it. help me somebody.

```
Dim objStreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("c:\FaultTypesByMonth.csv")
        Dim Str As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer       
        Dim headertext1(rsTerms.Columns.Count) As String
        Dim k As Integer = 0
        Dim arrcols As String = Nothing
        For Each column As DataColumn In TempTab.Columns
            headertext1(k) = column.ColumnName
            arrcols += column.ColumnName.ToString() + ","c
            k += 1
        Next

        objStreamWriter.WriteLine(arrcols)
        For i = 0 To (TempTab.Rows.Count - 1)
            For j = 0 To (TempTab.Columns.Count - 1)

                'this IF statement stops it from adding a comma after the last field
                If j = (TempTab.Columns.Count - 1) Then
                    Str = (TempTab.Rows(i)(j).ToString)
                Else
                    Str = (TempTab.Rows(i)(j).ToString & ",")
                End If
                objStreamWriter.Write(Str)
            Next
            objStreamWriter.WriteLine()
        Next
        objStreamWriter.Close()

' After save the file in C:/  I want to save the same file in any other Path for my convenience.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Dim sd As New SaveFileDialog
        sd.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv"
        sd.FileName = "FaultTypesByMonth"
        If sd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            'save the file here
            Debug.WriteLine("Save file location:" + sd.FileName)
        End If
```

Comment: Get the user input and where you give the path to the writer, replace your path with the relevant user portion.

Comment: Mr Allan thanks to respond, but i am not understand your intention.After save the file in some path, how can i open that file, and how to choose my desire path to save it. Please explain Briefly.

Comment: @user3463529 in your form use `SaveFileDialog` control

Comment: @user3463529 make the file writing code a function (Sub) which takes the path as a parameter, then you can call it with the user entered file path. Alternatively use File.Copy to copy the file from the source path to the user specified path.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a console application you could read a path argument from the [command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx).

If it's a GUI application you can show a save file dialog box, in WinForms use the [SaveFileDialog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To save a file to different locations put the writer code in a function which takes the file path as an argument:

```
 Sub SaveFile(filePath As String)
     Dim objStreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
     ' ... your code here
 End Sub

 Sub ButtonClick
     SaveFile("c:\FaultTypesByMonth.csv")
     ' ... SaveFileDialog code
     SaveFile(sd.Filename)
 End Sub
```

To copy a file use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 ' ... SaveFileDialog code
 File.Copy("c:\FaultTypesByMonth.csv", sd.Filename)
```

Comment: Hi there, Please check my commnt above.

Comment: If you want to save a copy of the file in a user specified path, either use the same code you used to write the file originally using the new path, or copy the file using File.Copy

Comment: if Yes, which Namespace i have to use.

Comment: Yes, File.Copy is available from .Net 2.0 onwards (including VB.Net 2005), and it's in the System.IO namespace (as is StreamWriter)

Comment: Thanks to all, Finally got the result

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SaveFileDialog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Simple example:

```
Private Sub SaveFile()
    Dim sd As New SaveFileDialog
    sd.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    If sd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'save the file here
        Debug.WriteLine("Save file location:" + sd.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Wilko,thanks for respond, i want to save file in any other location,which already saved by my application, this file made by my application and saving in perticular drive.very next, Now i want to save that file in my desired path. Your provided code only open the dialog box with file name but not save file in desired path.

Comment: You probably want to set the `InitialDirectory` property then. Have a look at the documentation

Comment: Please don't edit an answer by inserting your own code. Modify your original question instead. PS It is always best to add your existing code to a question initially as it helps everyone to see the problem.